# JBOX2d: restart a game

Tags: refresh, processing, physics, jbox2d

can anyone show the correct code to reset a game when using physics engine (JBOX2D)?
I am working on a game using Processing and I am unable to reset the game so that the user can play another round.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A google search will bring you to this page:

[JBox2D with BoxWrap2D Tutorial](http://www.processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1247034244.html)

from which I can see that doing

```
physics.destroy();
physics = new Physics(this, width, height);
```

and recreating your objects will reset the sketch..